# Focus next input once reaching maxlength value in react without jQuery and accept only numeric values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two questions about input in react.
Is there any way that I can make input automatically focus next field once reaching maxLength with react **without using jquery**.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" maxLength="4" />
    <input type="text" maxLength="4" />
    <input type="text" maxLength="4" />
</form>
```

the second question is how can I make input accept only numerical values when **type="text"**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the onChange event handler for this. When the user typed MAX_LENGTH (4 characters), the focus is set to the next element. React.findDOMNode gets the next DOM node corresponding to a React component. The focus method on the DOM node sets the focus.

```
handleTextChange(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length <= MAX_LENGTH) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }
  if (e.target.value.length === MAX_LENGTH) {
    React.findDOMNode(this.nextComponent).focus();
  }
}
```

The component JSX is:

```
<input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
<input ref={c => this.nextComponent=c} />
```

The nextComponent is set in ref. The `this.nextComponent` is used by React.findDOMNode to get the DOM node corresponding to the next component.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here. Can you explain?

Comment: @Dan, Updated the answer with explanation.

Comment: For future readers: `React.findDOMNode` is deprecated, but you don't need to use it anyway.  Just use `this.nextComponent.focus();`

Answer (score 3):

I faced some errors with the code above. so i changed it like below and it's working well.

```
handleTextChange1(e) {
    if (e.length <= 1) {
      this.setState({value: e})
    }
    if (e.length === 1) {
      this.input2.focus();
    }
  }
```

and also in the TextInputComponent i have:

```
<TextInput
    ref= {(input) => this.input1 = input}
    selectTextOnFocus={true}
    onChangeText={this.handleTextChange1}/>

<TextInput
    ref= {(input) => this.input2 = input}
    selectTextOnFocus={true}
    onChangeText={this.handleTextChange2}/>
```